# Computational Tree and Graphs to simulate ND Turing Machine

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, computation-theory, turing-machines

I'm trying to write a C code to simulate a Non Deterministic Turing Machine. So far i've already implemented the input tape and the transition tape, using a simple double linked list for the first, and a linked list for the second.

The idea was to build a Computational Tree like this: [Computational Tree](https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/projects/embedded/research/vis/doc/VisUser/vis_user/_5935_figure250.gif)

Where each node consists in a configuration of my Turing Machine:

1. Current State
2. Content of the Input Tape
3. Position of the Pointer in the Input tape

Because of non determinism i have to check and run recursively through the whole tree, which implies avery large amount of memory allocation ( 1 node for each possible configuration ).

Is there a better data structure to simulate a ND Turing Machine? I was thinking about **Orientated Graphs** (which is also what you usually use to describe a Turing Machine on paper) and implement it using an **Adjacency List** like suggested here: [Adjacency list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/) (because i don't know a priori the number of possible states, and arrays in C are not dynamic).

Comment: Before you get too far, why do it in C? You are talking a lot about objects and containers. Newer languages (dare I say c++) have those in bucket loads!

Comment: Yep, i'm aware of that, but it's a costraint imposed by a project!

Comment: Ok. Well remember you have realloc if you need to grow a list.